# MarkLogic search relevancy wieghts

Tags: search, marklogic, relevance

I want to know if:

```
cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("ts:title"), "Machines", (), 2)
```

has the same effect as setting weight for the title `element = 4` from
Admin API-Configure – Databases – top-songs – Word Query.

I understand that changing the config from admin api will have the effect on the entire database permanently , whereas doing through the query will be only applicable for that query.

Comment: I guess you meant to say weight `2` twice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word Query section for a Database in the Admin ui is used for `cts:word-query`, not for `cts:element-word-query`. So, I think the answer is actually no, it is not the same.

It is correct though that settings in the Word Query section apply to all uses of `cts:word-query` against that Database, while options to cts queries in general apply to that one use only.

HTH!